# Last array in JavaScript, why?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found out that if we do a code to get first and last arrays like this:

```
function firstLast(array) {
 var first = array[0];
 var last = array[array.length - 1];
return [first, last];
}
```

It works, I found that solution to get last array in the internet, but I can’t figure out why the - 1 would give the last instead of the first index since the array itself is counting 0, 1, 2, 3... from the lowest to highest. 
So why is that? The ++ would not work for that? Can someone give me explanation and/or examples please?

Comment: Since the indexes are 0 based, the last index is alway 1 less than the length of the array.

Comment: Have you tried seeing what `array.length - 1` is?

Comment: the index you're using is not `-1`, it's `array.length - 1` instead; which should indeed give you the last index

Comment: If you have 5 elements in the array the indexes are 0,1,2,3,4.
Now `array.length` will return 5, so you need to substract 1 to get 4.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that you can try in the console:

```
var places = ['first', 'second', 'third']
=> undefined

places[0]
=> "first"

places.length
=> 3

places.indexOf('third')
=> 2

places.length-1
=> 2

places[places.length-1]
=> "third"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, seems so easy now that it’s explained. But i couldn’t think about that.. all arrays starts as 0 so - 1 in length shall give the last index value, that would not work in php with index starting as 1 right? Thanks everyone